# Using pro and ab in place of ante and post?

Tags: grammar-choice, word-choice, preposition

I wanted to change windows to use the unabbreviated *ante meridiem* and *post meridiem* for A.M. and P.M., but they're one letter too long. Google Translate lists *pro* and *ab* as alternate translations for "before" and "after", respectively. Would using that make sense in this context? Thanks!

Comment: If they're one letter too long, you could get rid of the space; Latin was conventionally written without those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Oxford Latin Dictionary* lists syncopated forms for *post meridiem*: *posmeridiem* and *pomeridiem* (cf. Italian *pomeriggio*); both of these would be short enough for your needs. However, although *OLD* has entries for both, the only attestation I've managed to find so far is Quintilian, *Institutio oratoria* 9.4.39, which actually has *pos meridiem* in the version of the text (Winterbottom's 1970 edition) that appears on the [PHI](http://latin.packhum.org) site:

> Inde 'belligerare', 'pos meridiem' et illa Censori Catonis 'dicae' 'faciae'que, m littera in e mollita. Quae in ueteribus libris reperta mutare imperiti solent, et dum librariorum insectari uolunt inscientiam, suam confitentur.

(*OLD* cites this passage in the entry for *meridies* but prints *pomeridiem* instead of *pos meridiem*.)

As for an alternative to *ante meridiem*, *OLD* does list *promeridie* as an adverb, but the only attestation given is for an inscription (*CIL* 6.2104.20):

> PROMERIDIE FRATRES ARVALES PRAETEXTAS ACCEPER<UNT>

Still, there's some support there for the prepositional phrase *pro meridie* that you asked about.

Otherwise, the only thing I can think of is *mane* ('early in the day', 'in the morning'), though I'm not sure how well it works here. I'd be interested to see other opinions.

*Update:* Overall, I think it makes the most sense just to omit the interword spaces, as Draconis has suggested in a comment. Not only did the Romans often leave out such spaces in writing, as noted in the comment, but *antemeridiem* as a single word has its own entry in *OLD* (but not in Lewis & Short), and the entry for *meridies* in *OLD* notes that *post meridiem* can likewise be a single word.

Answer (score 6):

*Pro* means 'before' in the sense of 'in front of, in the presence of', as in *he stood before the judge,* but to my knowledge doesn't have a temporal sense.

*Ab* means 'after' in the sense of 'from, since', as in *I've like snow since childhood,* but that's all.

Neither quite has the meaning you're looking for.

Comment: Moreover, both pro and ab require a noun in the ablative, not the accusative.